# Como posso remover cada link que aponta para um vídeo, após o termino do vídeo?

Tags: javascript, loop, vídeo

Tenho esta `div` abaixo, nomeadamente com `id` e tendo dentro da mesma os elementos `p` seguido `a`(âncora):

```js
var vid = document.getElementById('player');

var link = document.getElementById('lista').getElementsByTagName('a');

var el = document.getElementById('lista').getElementsByTagName('p');

var src0 = vid.src;

var href0 = link.href;

var fonte = [
 "https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/animais_cantando.webm",
 "https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/equipment_these_days.webm",
 "https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/peck_pocketed.webm"
],
    clone = [
 "https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/animais_cantando.webm",
 "https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/equipment_these_days.webm",
 "https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/peck_pocketed.webm"
];

    function proximo() {
     if (fonte.length === 0) {
         fonte = clone.slice(0);
     }
     var indice = fonte.splice(0, 1);
     vid.src = indice;
     vid.autoplay = indice;
 }
window.setInterval(function() {
     var seg = vid.duration - vid.currentTime;

     if ((seg - 1) < 0)

 for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {

 if(src0 == href0) // comparar se o atributo src no elemento video e igual a do atributo href

 el[i].outerHTML = '';

 delete el[i].item(0);

  proximo();

 break;
  }
 }, 1000);

proximo();
```

```html
<video id="player" preload controls></video>

<hr>

<div id='lista'>
     <p><a href="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/animais_cantando.webm">Animais cantando</a></p>
     <p><a href="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/equipment_these_days.webm">Equipment these days</a></p>
     <p><a href="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/peck_pocketed.webm">Peck Pocketed</a></p>
</div>
```

Bom, observe bem o meu código-fonte e note que estou fazendo isso automaticamente, sem clicar diretamente no link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa `el[i].parentNode.removeChild(el[i]);` em vez de  `delete el[i].item(0);`

```js
var vid = document.getElementById('player');
var link = document.getElementById('lista').getElementsByTagName('a');
var el = document.getElementById('lista').getElementsByTagName('p');

var src0 = vid.src;
var href0 = link.href;
var fonte = [
  "https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/animais_cantando.webm",
  "https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/equipment_these_days.webm",
  "https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/peck_pocketed.webm"
];
var clone = fonte.slice();

function proximo() {
  if (fonte.length === 0) {
    fonte = clone.slice(0);
  }
  var indice = fonte.splice(0, 1);
  vid.src = indice;
  vid.autoplay = indice;
}
window.setInterval(function() {
  var seg = vid.duration - vid.currentTime;
  if ((seg - 1) < 0)
    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
      if (src0 == href0) // comparar se o atributo src no elemento video e igual a do atributo href
        el[i].outerHTML = '';
      el[i].parentNode.removeChild(el[i]);
      proximo();
      break;
    }
}, 1000);

proximo();
```

```html
<video id="player" preload controls></video>
<hr>
<div id='lista'>
  <p><a href="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/animais_cantando.webm">Animais cantando</a></p>
  <p><a href="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/equipment_these_days.webm">Equipment these days</a></p>
  <p><a href="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/peck_pocketed.webm">Peck Pocketed</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Parece que funcionou com seu método aplicado! Era apenas um detalhe que havia ignorado usar `el[i].parentNode.removeChild(el[i]);` em vez de `delete el[i].item(0);`, pois o `delete el[i].item(0);` tornaria-se Cross-browser. Mas infelizmente pra isso nao deu certo :(

Comment: @DiegoHenrique `delete el[i].item(0);` remove o elemento da lista que o `. getElementsByTagName` dá, mas não remove da página. Para remover da página tens de usar o método `. removeChild()`